# Query jsonb column in Postgres against multiple values

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a column 'carInfo' of type `jsonb`in my PostgreSQL database and I want to be able to query against multiple values. I want the query to return only those rows that match all criteria. For example, if I had multiple columns, I would write the query like this:

```
select * 
from car 
where name = 'BMW' 
AND 'year' = 2020
```

Since my column is of type `jsonb` I can make use of the containment operator (@>) like this:

```
select * 
from car 
where carInfo @> cast('{"name":"BMW"}') as jsonb 
  AND carInfo @> cast('{"year":"2020"}')
```

but I want the query to be dynamic, so that the user can query by any attributes they want.

So, they will send a list of search terms (in this case, the elements of that list would be `{"name":"BMW"}` and `{"year":"2020"}`.

Assuming, that I have the list as above, how would the query look like if I wanted to achieve the same result as when using the AND operator?

I tried it like this:

```
select * 
from car 
where carInfo @> any(array['{"name":"BMW"}', '{"year":"2020"}']::jsonb[])
```

but it acts the same way as when using the OR operator. I need to find those rows that contain BOTH the search terms

Comment: You could merge all those key/values into a single `jsonb` value and see if `carInfo` contains that, eg `SELECT * FROM car WHERE carInfo @> '{"name": "BMW", "year": 2020}'`. Your `@> any(...)` solution could be changed to `@> all(...)` to make it an `AND`, but I would highly recommend doing the single `@>` operation instead if you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `@> ALL`, but this should be better:

```
WHERE carInfo @> cast('{"name":"BMW", "year": "2020"}' as jsonb)
```

Comment: Thanks. For me this worked only when `as jsonb` is inside cast function

Comment: @KiraAG Unsurprising, since my answer contains a typo. I have fixed it, thanks for the hint.